# Famo.us physics engine: forces and walls not behaving as expected

Tags: physics, famo.us

I am tyring to create a grid of particles, using the famous physics engine. I thought that if 25 particles were placed beteween 4 bounding walls (forming a square) and they all had an equal repulsion force to each other, they would naturally form a grid - ie. they would all be held as far away from each other as possible, given the limits of their world. I expected this to work, even if the particles were just added without an initial position. However, even if I give them an initial position, they don't hold in place unless the force is very small.

Also, I thought that if a wall had a restitution of 0, then a particle would just stop on colliding with it. When I run the code below, I can see particles bouncing off walls. The pen is at:
[`http://codepen.io/timsig/pen/pJJrOa`](http://codepen.io/timsig/pen/pJJrOa)

What am I failing to grasp? - thanks in advance

```
define('main', function (require, exports, module) {
     // import dependencies
    var Engine = require('famous/core/Engine');
    var Surface = require('famous/core/Surface')
    var Modifier = require('famous/core/Modifier');
    var PhysicsEngine = require('famous/physics/PhysicsEngine');
    var Particle = require('famous/physics/bodies/Particle');
    var Drag = require('famous/physics/forces/Drag');
    var RepulsionForce = require('famous/physics/forces/Repulsion');
    var Wall            = require('famous/physics/constraints/Wall');

    var gridItems = [];

    var positionsArray = [-140,-70,0,70,140];

    var context = Engine.createContext();

    var physics = new PhysicsEngine();




    var gridR = new RepulsionForce({
        strength: 0.015
    });

    //physics.addBody(planetParticle);
  var leftWall    = new Wall({normal : [1,0,0],  distance : 140, restitution : 0});
    var rightWall   = new Wall({normal : [-1,0,0], distance : 140, restitution : 0});
    var topWall     = new Wall({normal : [0,1,0],  distance : 140, restitution : 0});
    var bottomWall  = new Wall({normal : [0,-1,0], distance : 140, restitution : 0});



    function gridItemTrans() {
         return this.particle.getTransform();
    }

    function addGridRepulsion(){
      var sq1, sq2;
      for (var i = 0; i < gridItems.length; i += 1){
        sq1 = gridItems[i].particle;
        physics.attach([leftWall, rightWall, topWall, bottomWall], sq1);
          if ((i + 1) < gridItems.length){
            for (var j = i + 1; j < gridItems.length; j += 1){
              sq2 = gridItems[j].particle;
              physics.attach(gridR, sq1, sq2);
            }
            }
        }
      }

    function addBodies(){
      gridItems.forEach(function(ele){
        physics.addBody(ele.particle);
      });
    }

    for (var rows = 0; rows < 5; rows += 1){

        for (var cols = 0; cols < 5; cols += 1){

          var gridItem = new Surface({
            properties: {
                backgroundColor: '#23AD23'
            }
            }); 

           gridItem.particle = new Particle({
            position: [positionsArray[rows], positionsArray[cols], 0]
           });

           //physics.addBody(gridItem.particle);
           //physics.attach(centralG, gridItemParticle[rows][cols], planetParticle);

           gridItem.modifier = new Modifier({
            size: [50,50],
            align: [0.5, 0.5],
            origin: [0.5, 0.5],
            transform: gridItemTrans.bind(gridItem)
           });

           context.add(gridItem.modifier).add(gridItem);
           gridItems.push(gridItem);
        }
    }
  addBodies();
  addGridRepulsion();



});
```

Comment: Just a note: `Famo.us` is rewriting their physics engine in the next release `MixedMode` and hopefully it will be more complete and make more sense.  `Famo.us` really never really released this version of the physics engine in documentation or support. (v0.3.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clear up your understanding, we will fist look at the repulsion being applied.

By Default, the `Repulsion` decay function in `Famo.us` is a `gravity` function (an inverse squared distance decay function). Gravity has a decay based on mass and distance.

```
var gridR = new RepulsionForce({
  strength: 1,
  decayFunction : RepulsionForce.DECAY_FUNCTIONS.GRAVITY
});
```

You can apply a `linear` function to your repulsion decay and you will create the affect you are looking for.

```
var gridR = new RepulsionForce({
  strength: 1,
  decayFunction : RepulsionForce.DECAY_FUNCTIONS.LINEAR
});
```

If gravity were to decay linearly rather than quadratically, you would need infinite kinetic energy to escape a gravitational field. It would be like living in 2D space.

To answer the second part of your question: The walls have no restitution, but the particles still respond to the force of the other particles.

Comment: Thank you once again. That makes a lot more sense now. I had noticed what you mentioned in your comment; the documentation is sparse, so I've been trying to cobble together an understanding from looking at demo code and questions like this. Hopefully this improves with the next release, and we'll all be playing magic keyboards.

Comment: I've experimented a little further, and it's raised more questions. The force itself does not position the particles; they just stay where they are put (all on top of each other at the origin of the engine if nothing is specified). I thought if they all repelled each other they would form themselves into a grid (equal distances between all particles). Also, if I position them in a grid and then give the central one some velocity, none of the other particles are affected. Thanks again for any help.

Comment: By "a decay over time" you certainly mean "a decay over distance", don't you? If gravity was to decay with time, that would be very bad news for our universe :)

Comment: Yes, good catch. Gravity is a function of mass and the distance of two objects. Must have been on a different thought process when typing. :)